# Why can't I assign the int variable i to the int pointer *ip? They are both int

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to learn the concept of pointer and reference. Could someone please explain to me why the code below is illegal? Why can't I assign the int variable `i` to the int pointer `*ip`? They are both int. I'm really struggling with the concept.

```
int i = 0;

int *ip = i;
```

Comment: what do you expect `int *ip = i;` to do exactly? Where would it point?

Comment: Because `i` and `ip` have different types i.e. `i` can hold integers (e.g. 10, 56, 45678 etc.) and `ip` can hold memory address  of some variable of type `int`. Hence, int* ip = i is not a valid statement.

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything, just trying to learn the concept of pointer and reference, see how it works exactly. @M.M

Comment: @dzjustinli your question text suggests that you expected `int *ip = i;` to work, I'm asking what you expected it to mean when you tried this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *ip
```

is a variable known as a [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) that could hold a memory address of a variable of type `int`. `i` is of type `int`, so to use the pointer correctly, type

```
int *ip = &i;
```

which stores the memory address of `i` into the pointer `ip`.

Answer (score 2):

**ip** is a pointer and **pointer** must be hold the **address of another variable.**

```
int i = 0;
int *ip;
ip = &i;
```

or

```
int *ip = &i;
```

Answer (score -2):

In case

```
 int *ip = i;
```

you actually assign value `0` to pointer. I.e. `ip` has type `int *` - pointer to `int`, and it is not `int`.
If you want assign `0` to pointer use

```
 int *ip = NULL; // good way
```

or

```
 int *ip = (int *)i; // incorrect pointer initialization with explicit type conversion
```

In general, assignment to pointer have to be `NULL` or address of allocated memory (allocated with `new` or `malloc` or address of existing variable taken with unary `&` operator), e.g.

```
 int *ip = NULL;
 ip = &i; // address of variable
 ip = malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocation in C style
 ip = new int; // allocation in C++ style
```

then value can be assigned to allocated memory with pointer as follows:

```
 *ip = i; // here pointer value (address) is not changed
```

To see address (value of pointer) and pointed value test that statement:

```
 std::cout << "Adress " << ip << " contains value " << *ip << std::endl;
```

Comment: `malloc` should be avoided in C++. (In fact `ip = malloc(sizeof(int));` is ill-formed). `int *ip = i;` is ill-formed (a cast is required to assign integer to pointer unless it is a null pointer constant - `i` isn't one even though it currently holds value 0)

Comment: it is just an example, you can use `new` in C++